what is more accurate for checking nvme smartmontools or nvme-cli
Note this is not a question about using this tools.
Since a few weeks smartmontools is complaining over one of my ssd/nvme-standart. In jammy and debian and it makes me nervous.
     nvme list
Node                  Generic               SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
--------------------- --------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme1n1          /dev/ng1n1            S3TNNF0K821653       SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7               1         126,61  GB / 512,11  GB    512   B +  0 B   5L2QEXA7
/dev/nvme0n1          /dev/ng0n1            A21E073B177C00025510 SSDPH1TB073TKP1                          1           1,02  TB /   1,02  TB    512   B +  0 B   EDFM00.7

I want to test it, just in case. But I'm unsure which tool to use. During my search I only find something how to use them.
I hope my question is not kinda opinion based.
